# Merging 2 SQL tables with same table convention design without using update command

Tags: sql, database, merge

I have 2 tables in my SQL database:

[image]

And I want to merge them in a way the result will be:

[image]

This is just an example for 2 tables which need to be merged into one new table (The tables contain an example data, the statement should work for any amount of data inside the tables).

The ID which got different value in CSV should be updated into the new table for example:

ID 3's value is 'KKK' and in table T is 'CCC', then what should be updated is the CSV table.

Comment: Are there more than two columns in this table? And you don't want 9 and 11 to appear in the new table?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - yes there will be only 2 columns and for the the IDS let's say we can accept both solutions

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `left join` and to match to the second table if available:

```
select t.id, coalesce(csv.value, t.value) as value
from t left join
     csv
     on t.id = csv.id;
```

If you want this in a new table, use the appropriate construct for your database, or use `insert` to insert into an existing table.

Comment: this will create a new table?

Comment: @lupacshakur . . . This is the logic to generate the result set you want.  You would use whatever mechanism your *unstated* database uses to put it into a table.

Comment: This will guarntee the union between both of the tables and in a matter there is no matching id it will take the CSV id and value? as shown in the result table example ?

Comment: as for your solution it will duplicate the columns where there are the same "id" value for example it will create 2 columns with 2 identical id with different value it will not overwrite the value according to CSV table.

Comment: @tupacshakur . . . No idea what your comment means.  The result set has two columns, the `id` and `value`.  The `id` are all the `id`s in `t`.  The value comes first from `csv` and then from `t`.  Your sample data  has no duplicates in either table; in that case, this produces no duplicates in the result table.